# How can I merge 2 lists and between them stays number 1 by creating lists of lists of 3-tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to merge two lists and place a 1 between them and create a lists of lists 3-tuples (inner list size is varying) .And  l2 and the flattened version of l1 have the same size. Example lists:

```
l1=[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2]]
l2=[x,y,z,t,u]
```

I want to produce the following list:

```
l3=[[(a1,1,x),(b1,1,y),(c1,1,z)],[(a2,1,t),(b2,1,u)]]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Why is it `(b2,1,v)` and not `(b2,1,u)` in the last element of the expected result?

Comment: Ahh sorry that is a typo

Answer (score 0):

```
l3=[] # final list
index=0 # keeps index for l2
for lst in l1: # loop through all lists in l1
    l=[]
    for elm in lst: # loop through all elements in the inner list(lst) of l1
        l.append((elm,1,l2[index])) # for elements in lst create wanted tuple
        index+=1 # next tuple contains next element of l2
    l3.append(l) # append created list of tuples to l3
```

Comment: This answer (while possibly correct, I don't know) could use some comments or explanatory text. Remember the goal is also to *explain* vs. just provide code student or developer can just cut-and-paste.